# trying to create simple plugin to filter categories from all authors

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, filters

i want to restrict all authors to spesific categories i already done it but via theme function.php, i trying to build as a plugin:

this my plugin content:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: My Restricted 
* Plugin URI: 
* Description: Restrcted
* Version: 0.0.1 
* Author: mm
* Author URI: http://www.mm.com
* License: A "Mikvision" license  e.g. GPL12
*/


$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('author');
if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {  
function wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs($args, $taxonomies) {
    global $typenow;

    if ($typenow == 'post') {
        // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
        if (implode('', $taxonomies) == 'category') {
            $cats = array(11,13); // as an array

            if (empty($cats))
                $args['include'] = array(99999999); // no available categories
            else
                $args['include'] = $cats;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}


    add_filter('get_terms_args', 'wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2);
}
```

if u put it inside function.php of my theme its working but plugin not working showing white page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins run a lot earlier than themes - you need to delay the execution using a hook:

```
/**
 * Fire once WordPress is ready and conditionally hook our handler.
 */
function wpse_199197_init() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array( 'author' );

    if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) )
        add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_199197_init' );

function wpse_77670_filterGetTermArgs( $args, $taxonomies) {
    global $typenow;

    if ( $typenow == 'post' ) {
        // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
        if ( implode( '', $taxonomies ) == 'category' ) {
            $cats = array( 11, 13 ); // as an array

            if ( empty( $cats ) )
                $args['include'] = array( 99999999 ); // no available categories
            else
                $args['include'] = $cats;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, always develop with [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). That white screen will now contain error messages to help you determine the problem.

Refer to the [action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the order in which things happen during the load process.

Your plugin is loaded before the `plugins_loaded` action, which is when your code runs. However, note that the current user isn't authenticated until 7 steps later, so `$user = wp_get_current_user();` can't possibly succeed. As a rule of thumb, you'll almost never have code that executes in a plugin file when loaded, everything you do in WordPress will be hooked to run on an action of some sort.